# Windows fatal exception: access violation with tensorboard

Tags: python, tensorflow

I installed tensorflow in the following steps
1, Install anaconda in win 10
2, conda install -c anaconda tensorflow-gpu=1.14
I can use this to train my model, but when I use tensorboard,  `tensorboard --logdir=logs --host localhost --port 8080`, the error occurs, I have tried to reinstall tensorflow, but got the same error, Besides, I have tried to use `127.0.0.1` to replace `localhost`, still nothing, for detail:

```
W1031 11:17:07.819002 12044 plugin_event_accumulator.py:294] Found more than one graph event per run, or there was a metagraph containing a graph_def, as well as one or more graph events.  Overwriting the graph with the newest event.
W1031 11:17:07.820028 12044 plugin_event_accumulator.py:302] Found more than one metagraph event per run. Overwriting the metagraph with the newest event.
I1031 11:17:08.197018  7448 _internal.py:122] 127.0.0.1 - - [31/Oct/2019 11:17:08] "[37mGET /data/environment HTTP/1.1[0m" 200 -
I1031 11:17:08.314679 13608 _internal.py:122] 127.0.0.1 - - [31/Oct/2019 11:17:08] "[37mGET /data/runs HTTP/1.1[0m" 200 -
I1031 11:17:08.324679  2524 _internal.py:122] 127.0.0.1 - - [31/Oct/2019 11:17:08] "[37mGET /data/experiments HTTP/1.1[0m" 200 -
Windows fatal exception: access violation

Thread 0x00002914 (most recent call first):

Thread 0x000032f8 (most recent call first):

Thread 0x000009dc (most recent call first):
  File "D:\Dev\anaconda3\lib\socket.py", line 589 in readinto
  File "D:\Dev\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 358 in handle_one_request
  File "D:\Dev\anaconda3\lib\http\server.py", line 428 in handle
  File "D:\Dev\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 327 in handle
  File "D:\Dev\anaconda3\lib\socketserver.py", line 720 in __init__
  File "D:\Dev\anaconda3\lib\socketserver.py", line 360 in finish_request
  File "D:\Dev\anaconda3\lib\socketserver.py", line 650 in process_request_thread
  File "D:\Dev\anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 870 in run
  File "D:\Dev\anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 926 in _bootstrap_inner
  File "D:\Dev\anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 890 in _bootstrap

Current thread 0x00002f84 (most recent call first):
  File "D:\Dev\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\lib\io\file_io.py", line 84 in _preread_check
  File "D:\Dev\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\lib\io\file_io.py", line 122 in read
  File "D:\Dev\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\lib\io\file_io.py", line 333 in read_file_to_string
  File "D:\Dev\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\checkpoint_management.py", line 273 in get_checkpoint_state
  File "D:\Dev\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\checkpoint_management.py", line 336 in latest_checkpoint
  File "D:\Dev\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\plugins\projector\projector_plugin.py", line 669 in _find_latest_checkpoint
  File "D:\Dev\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\plugins\projector\projector_plugin.py", line 409 in _read_latest_config_files
  File "D:\Dev\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\plugins\projector\projector_plugin.py", line 329 in configs
  File "D:\Dev\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\plugins\projector\projector_plugin.py", line 312 in _determine_is_active
  File "D:\Dev\anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 870 in run
  File "D:\Dev\anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 926 in _bootstrap_inner
  File "D:\Dev\anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 890 in _bootstrap

Thread 0x00001b30 (most recent call first):
  File "D:\Dev\anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 296 in wait
  File "D:\Dev\anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 552 in wait
  File "D:\Dev\anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 857 in start
  File "D:\Dev\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\plugins\profile\profile_plugin.py", line 135 in is_active
  File "D:\Dev\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\backend\application.py", line 284 in _serve_plugins_listing
  File "D:\Dev\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\wrappers\base_request.py", line 237 in application
  File "D:\Dev\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\backend\application.py", line 349 in __call__
  File "D:\Dev\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 292 in execute
  File "D:\Dev\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 304 in run_wsgi
  File "D:\Dev\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 362 in handle_one_request
  File "D:\Dev\anaconda3\lib\http\server.py", line 426 in handle
  File "D:\Dev\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 327 in handle
  File "D:\Dev\anaconda3\lib\socketserver.py", line 720 in __init__
  File "D:\Dev\anaconda3\lib\socketserver.py", line 360 in finish_request
  File "D:\Dev\anaconda3\lib\socketserver.py", line 650 in process_request_thread
  File "D:\Dev\anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 870 in run
  File "D:\Dev\anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 926 in _bootstrap_inner
  File "D:\Dev\anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 890 in _bootstrap

Thread 0x00003528 (most recent call first):
  File "D:\Dev\anaconda3\lib\socket.py", line 589 in readinto
  File "D:\Dev\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 358 in handle_one_request
  File "D:\Dev\anaconda3\lib\http\server.py", line 428 in handle
  File "D:\Dev\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 327 in handle
  File "D:\Dev\anaconda3\lib\socketserver.py", line 720 in __init__
  File "D:\Dev\anaconda3\lib\socketserver.py", line 360 in finish_request
  File "D:\Dev\anaconda3\lib\socketserver.py", line 650 in process_request_thread
  File "D:\Dev\anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 870 in run
  File "D:\Dev\anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 926 in _bootstrap_inner
  File "D:\Dev\anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 890 in _bootstrap

Thread 0x00001d18 (most recent call first):
  File "D:\Dev\anaconda3\lib\socket.py", line 589 in readinto
  File "D:\Dev\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 358 in handle_one_request
  File "D:\Dev\anaconda3\lib\http\server.py", line 428 in handle
  File "D:\Dev\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 327 in handle
  File "D:\Dev\anaconda3\lib\socketserver.py", line 720 in __init__
  File "D:\Dev\anaconda3\lib\socketserver.py", line 360 in finish_request
  File "D:\Dev\anaconda3\lib\socketserver.py", line 650 in process_request_thread
  File "D:\Dev\anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 870 in run
  File "D:\Dev\anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 926 in _bootstrap_inner
  File "D:\Dev\anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 890 in _bootstrap

Thread 0x00002f0c (most recent call first):
  File "D:\Dev\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\backend\application.py", line 436 in _reload
  File "D:\Dev\anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 870 in run
  File "D:\Dev\anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 926 in _bootstrap_inner
  File "D:\Dev\anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 890 in _bootstrap

Thread 0x000002bc (most recent call first):
  File "D:\Dev\anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 296 in wait
  File "D:\Dev\anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 552 in wait
  File "D:\Dev\anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 857 in start
  File "D:\Dev\anaconda3\lib\socketserver.py", line 665 in process_request
  File "D:\Dev\anaconda3\lib\socketserver.py", line 316 in _handle_request_noblock
  File "D:\Dev\anaconda3\lib\socketserver.py", line 237 in serve_forever
  File "D:\Dev\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 735 in serve_forever
  File "D:\Dev\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\program.py", line 233 in main
  File "D:\Dev\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\absl\app.py", line 250 in _run_main
  File "D:\Dev\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\absl\app.py", line 299 in run
  File "D:\Dev\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\main.py", line 64 in run_main
  File "D:\Dev\anaconda3\Scripts\tensorboard-script.py", line 10 in <module>
```

Comment: Hi, I had the same problem, I moved the tensorboard files into differnt folder and this caused the error. You can see the paths in file named 'checkpoint'

Comment: As you have solved this issue in [Github](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/33864) `by uninstalling TF 1.14 and installing back TF 1.13`. So Marking this issue as solved. Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0):

As user11530462 mentioned, uninstall tf1.14 and install tf1.13 will solve the problem.

You can clone your old environment first:

```
conda create --name new_env --clone old_env
```

And then

```
pip unisntall tensorflow-gpu

pip install tensorflow-gpu==1.13.1
```

And then run your code in the new environment to see if it works for you.